# failed to get keyring during saving token, key has been revoked

Tags: authentication, azcopy

```
inline string run_cmd(string cmd){
    string data;
    FILE * stream;

    constint max_buffer = 512s;
    charbuffer[max_buffer];

    stream = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
    if (stream){
        while (!feof(stream))
            if (fgets(buffer, max_buffer, stream) != NULL) data.append(buffer);
        pclose(stream);
    }
    return data;
}
```

run_cmd("azcopy login --identity;");

Get the below error msg:

```
{
    "run_cmd("azcopy login --identity;")": "\nFailed to perform login command: \nfailed to get keyring during saving token, key has been revoked\n\nNOTE: If your credential was created in the last 5 minutes, please wait a few minutes and try again.\n"
}
```

Trying to log in with azcopy from Linux RHEL 8.6.
The current Azcopy version is 10.17.0.
System has already installed this keyctl. We also try reinstall it but the same error occurs.

```
sudo apt install keyutils
keyctl session
```